# Angular: npm install returning "peer dependencies" warning, incompatible peer dependencies

Tags: angular, npm-install, node-modules, angular7

When I first did `npm install` I got bunch of warnings, below is just one example

```
    @angular/animations@7.2.10 requires a peer of @angular/core@7.2.10 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

(...skipping other warnings here...)

```
npm WARN angular-star-rating@4.0.0-beta.3 requires a peer of @angular/core@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular-star-rating@4.0.0-beta.3 requires a peer of @angular/forms@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

After seeing this warning  I updated my `package.json` and modified @angular/core which was `7.2.8 to 7.2.10`, and then did `npm install`. This second run gave me below warning

```
@angular/forms@7.2.8 requires a peer of @angular/core@7.2.8 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

What should I do in such case?

```
@angular/animations@7.2.10 needs @angular/core@7.2.10
@angular/forms@7.2.8 needs @angular/core@7.2.8.
@angular-star-rating@4.0.0-beta.3 requires @angular/core@^4.0.0
```

How to deal with it? 
Should I really update forms to @angular/forms@7.2.10?
Should I manually update each broken dependency?

Answer (score 0):

For @angular/ items, it's usually a good idea to update them all at the same time due to potential compatibility issues.

The Angular update guide is also very helpful.  Checkout the Angular CLI tools that help you with this process.  https://update.angular.io/